# PyQt tableview and edits to multiple selected cells

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtableview

Ive been working on a simple tableview model, ive hit a stumbling block when i want to edit multiple cells. 
Specifically I need to be able to change the checkstate on my cells checkboxes. When i select more then one cell and toggle the check boxes only the clicked cell updates its checkboxes. 
Any help would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a variable to store your selected cells. Then for all selected cells you force the checking by calling the [setCheckedState()](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qcheckbox.html#setCheckState) method.

Let me know if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I thought of doing it that way but i just cant see how and where i get this to work. I can get my selection from the view quite easily using view.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()

But how do I get my models checkBoxes to emit that it was clicked, and return the value of it to the selectedIndexes? I think its that logic that im unsure about.

Comment: The way I'd do it (I'm not saying it's the more efficient) would be to connect the click on a checkbox to a function. That function would check if there are other cells selected and check them too. Then you might need to update your view, but I'm not even sure about that.

Comment: That makes sense, tho i still cant find a way of connecting the checkbox from the cell to anything? Thats trick im missing i guess. I mean its not like a standard qt widget and its not a delegate its simply a cell set to be userCheckable. Its probably something really simple :¬)

Comment: Ive just setup my def for setting selected cells to a hard coded value. So All thats missing is the ability to set the value on clicked tableviews checkbox. Thanks for help so far.

Comment: Ok, I don't know why I thought you were using a delegate. Maybe because I'm struggling with them right now! For now all I can think of for your problem are nasty workarounds. I'll keep looking into it. Let me know if you find something before me :)

Comment: Sure will do. Maybe i will have to go down the delegate route... This simple spreadsheet is starting to get way more complex then I thought.

Comment: Hmm i did do a kinda hacky trick for this to work. I connected to the models dataChanged signal, and caught the selected items and set them to the returned indexes value. So that works.. in a kinda horrid way to be honest. Now my problem is my selection changes to the cell i just clicked. Seeing if i can reselect the items...

Comment: Oh yeah for the dataChanged signal to work i needed to set an "updating" attribute on my main object, so i can avoid an infinity loop. Really does feel like the wrong thing todo. I have a feeling I should be creating a checkbox delegate so i can emit a checkbox clicked signal.

Comment: Yes I think a delegate would be the proper/clean way to do this!